# jquery live executing multiple times

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="Content">
  <div class="MyDiv">...</div>
  <div class="MyDiv">...</div>
</div>
```

The MyDiv elements are removed and added several times as the result of an ajax call. I use the a function that uses the .html() function to replace the HTML.

When the page loads, I execute the following function:

```
function DynamicHandlers() {

     $('#Content .MyDiv').live({
        click: function () { .... },
        mouseleave: function () { ... }
    });
```

The problem is that the click and mouseleave handlers are executed as many time as I've changed the HTML. I initially had the handlers tied to the creation of the HTML and I'd bind the events each time the HTML was updated. I thought that by moving the handlers to the function that uses the .live(), I only had to run it once and then the handlers would be set for good. Which they are; the only problem is that they get executed multiple times.

What are the changes I need to make?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us the code calling `DynamicHandlers` please.

Comment: are you calling DynamicHandlers inside the load function? or is it in the content that is loaded?   we'll need to see the rest of your javascript to tell for sure what is going on.

Comment: It runs within the document.ready() function and it just gets called at that time.

Comment: aside: Use of delegated(jquery delegate) event handlers or "On/Off" is preffered over live.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `DynamicHandlers()` is not called multiple times? Try appending an alert() in the click event just to verify. Also, `.live()` is now deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. `.on()` should be used instead.

Comment: As a matter of fact, `live` is deprecated as of 1.7.

Comment: labroo makes a good point, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: ok ok, nevermind, it ran in the document ready function AND in the function that generated the html. sorry.

Comment: I suggest removing this question if it is not a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler will be invoked for each element in the DOM that matches the $('#Content .MyDiv') selector. I assume that at the time the event is fired there are multiple elements on the page that match.

Comment: nevermind, it ran in the document ready function AND in the function that generated the html. sorry

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to fix this is to put a .die() call before your .live().

this of course, isn't really the right thing to do, but it will fix it.

Comment: it's bad form.  .live is terrible anyway, and not really recommended to be used especially with the most recent version of jQuery.